# How to update questions for published multiple-choices quiz in SAKAI?

Tags: sakai

I have run many multiple-choice quizzes and some of my published questions have errors. I have made updates to those questions but when taking the quiz, my students still see the old errors as if the questions had never been updated.

So my question is how to update the published questions?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the only way is to update the questions is to publish a new quiz under a new name.

You probably don't want to do that, as you'll then have to sort out who should take the new quiz and what to do with the old scores.

The simplest remedy might be in the published quiz to choose Scores > Questions and manually override the troublesome questions.

I believe the logic that for way this works are reasons of fairness (perceived or actual) and archival purposes the questions remain as they were when published.

In the unpublished quiz you can add another answer through the edit option.  If the questions are there to edit, you can edit them, if the questions are drawn from a pool that's already been updated you can select "Update Questions" in Sakai 2.9 and greater, or simply Edit the part and save again in earlier versions of Sakai.

[image]

Comment: I see the reason why we cannot do the update and your suggested remedy seem the best thing to do - to serve the students best!

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to update the unpublished quizzes for future use. Thank you so much!